# Need to create a slicer which has one option 'Received' in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to get a filter in power bi  below is data, as there is a "sno" column present in data for each name. Neha appears in 2 rows as the "sno" differs Example "Neha". I need to check if both A and B is present for neha then Yes. ie. i need a filter which will have value "Yes" if user select checkbox against "Yes" then data related to only "Neha" and "Arti" should display in chart. when we compare "Neha" and "Arti" against "Dua" and "Arun" its not a valid scenario as "Dua" and "Arun" data is missing in one column.

### Name   class   sno    A       B

### Neha    11     A-1   10     Null

### Neha    11     B-1   Null   10

### Arti    12     A-2   30    Null

### Arti    12     B-2   Null   40

### Dua      9     A-3    20    Null

### Arun      8    B-4    Null   40

Data looks like below if we remove Sno column from it and the same way data is displayed on chart.

### Name   class   A   B

### Neha 11 10 10

### Arti 12 30 40

### Dua 9 20 Null

### Arun 8 Null 40

User requirement is when they select the checkbox "Yes". only the data against "neha" and Arti is displayed. I.e A=40 and B=50

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming we can apply sum on column A and B [download pbix file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V1DwlakdN643ccb6HfUYw-J0ExlktB3o)

then we can get the required output:

[image]

I have grouped the data in edit query and created a table "groupedby data" 
[image]

and then created a flag measure
***Flag = IF(or(GroupbyData[A]=BLANK(),GroupbyData[B]=BLANK()),"No","Yes")***